# gedit tool bar missing unless running as sudo

Tags: sudo, gedit

I'm really new and from the dark side (Windows)...

I must be doing something wrong.

The only way I can get gedit to run with a tool bar (Save As etc.) is to launch it with sudo from a terminal.

I have the same issue with FileZilla.  It runs in 'kiosk' mode (wont save passwords) unless its launched with sudo.

Is there some setting for me as a regular user, that will allow these applications to run in 'adult' mode when placed on the left icon bar on the desktop?

I see FileZilla has irritated other and maybe that's the way it is,  but gedit?

Shouldn't I be able to have a full featured text editor without becoming a root user?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whether a toolbar is shown or not, is just a GTK user setting. Do not run regular programs as root, unless really required. I don't remember what exact setting it was and how to change it - that's why I'm not providing an answer, but just commenting.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Also run run gedit from terminal without sudo, maybe it will output some error message.

Comment: running from the terminal (no sudo) produces a gedit without a toolbar (same as launching it from the desktop search, it has only about 14 buttons but is missing many options .. not sure how I post up a screen shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Global menu

This is the expected behaviour in a default Ubuntu/Unity installation where all application menus are integrated as a globalmenu in the top panel:

[image]

It is [possible to disable this feature](https://askubuntu.com/a/311783/3940) but I would not recommend you do it at the time now. You will likely get used to this behaviour soon and you will enjoy to have all application's menus always in the same place, and often out of the way of your application's main window.

#### Why not for Root?

It is the super user Root who runs applications when you call them with `sudo` or `gksu`. Since Root does not run your desktop (in fact Root does not have a desktop at all) the application's menu can not be integrated to the top panel and are shown as usual.

However it is not recommended to run graphical applications as root because you will then have enough power accidentally harm your otherwise very stable OS.

Comment: Good answer, assuming OP means the *menu bar* rather than the *toolbar*.

Comment: Takkat,  I'm still confused here.  I'm a developer (Windows full stack), and will doing mostly nodes and angularjs.  I will be spending most of my  time in a text editor and a terminal window.  I need gedit with a toolbar or some other editor.  Although I may 'get used to this behavior',  it isn't going to work for a text editor.  Being told 'Don't sudo gedit' ... doesn't help.   Did I install the wrong distro?  Is there a link to info on what a developers machine would look like?

Comment: I'm currently running in VMware and am itching to do a 'real' install, but feel that my 13.04 default install may have been a bad choice for what I want to do.     Thanks in advance for your patience and help!

Comment: Completely off-topic here, but why don't you use SSH (PuTTY on Windows) and WinSCP to connect to the VM directly without the hassle of using the GUI of the VMware machine? Then you can use your favourite Windows tools if you like while running the server thingies in the virtual machine.

Comment: I gave up on the VM took my old Win7 box and did a 'real' install.  What a difference!  other than needing to use the NVida driver to get the fan to stop screaming .. very nice.  thanks for your patience, ... I've a lot to learn .

Comment: Great!! It is more fun indeed to have Ubuntu running on bare metal :)